# What view object is the base for Apple's Calendar App (iOS/OS X)

Tags: ios, objective-c, macos, uitableview

I am working on a project where I need to display information in a similar fashion as the well known Calendar apps from Apple do.

I'm trying to figure out whether I should use an UICollectionView or a UITableView as a base class.

Which one is better fit for the task, why? Possible alternatives?

Comment: Those apps have lots of views in them. Can you be more specific?

Comment: Consider there's more than looks going on there on OS X. They're able to scroll infinitely in future or past directions by time intervals. There's a lot happening to make it seem so simple and smooth and obvious. View recycling is one. Fancy drawing to opt in to Responsive Scrolling is another. It's a much more sophisticated view than its simplicity would imply

Comment: I have already accepted a solution which is fairly complete.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve similar look with `UICollectionView` with a custom layout. There's a great example, matching your target, in [Custom Collection View Layouts at objc.io](http://www.objc.io/issue-3/collection-view-layouts.html).

Comment: Thank you so much for the very quick reply. Its a good reference.